# OOP with jQuery Click event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I have this code:

```
var beer = function(){};

$.extend(beer.prototype, {
    types:{
        '.beer':'boom',
        '.beer_pick':'pack',
        '.beer_tes':'fix',
    },

    init:function() {
        var me = this;
        $.each(this.types, function(key, value) {
            me.update(key, value);
        });
    },
    update:function(className, actionName) {
        $(className + ' .bb').click(function() {
            $(this).parent().find('.cc').load('try.php?do=beer&action=' + actionName);
            alert("TEST");
        });
    },
    pics:{
        add:function(element) {
            $.post("try.php?do=beer&action=pic", {
                id:$(element).data('id'),
                name:$(element).data('name'),
            });
        }
    }
});
beer = beer.prototype;
beer.init();
```

In the function `update` the click event not working,
After i click on the element, nothing happens.

When i pull the click event out of the function, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    className = '.beer';
    actionName = 'boom';
    $(className + ' .bb').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().find('.cc').load('try.php?do=beer&action=' + actionName);
        alert("TEST");
    });
});
```

It work.
Why? how can i fix this?

**Another question:**
There is better way instead:

```
beer = beer.prototype;
beer.init();
```

Comment: Try to init in the document ready event handler, `$(ntf.init)`

Comment: in the second example, you're waiting until the document is ready

Comment: What if in your function you try - `var clickClass = className + ' .bb'; $(document).on('click', clickClass, function(){ });` Also, are you sure when you call it the correct `className` is being passed into the function?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy It not working.

Comment: @aw04 Ok, what can i do to fix this?

Comment: @Adjit It not working. And yes.

Comment: wrap the init call or whatever in a document.ready, @RajaprabhuAravindasamy comment is the shorthand

Comment: `var beer = function...` beer should be capitalized. Then instead of `beer = beer.prototype` you want `var beer = new Beer(); beer.init();`